# How to Automate NULL Object Creation

Tags: r

This question actual just became alot more interesting.

My question is simple.  How do I automate this?

```
g.names<-NULL
g.names1<-NULL
g.names2<-NULL
g.names3<-NULL
g.names4<-NULL
g.names5<-NULL
g.names6<-NULL
g.names7<-NULL
g.names8<-NULL
g.names9<-NULL
g.names10<-NULL
g.names11<-NULL
g.names12<-NULL

gt.names<-list(
g.names1=g.names1, 
g.names2=g.names2, 
g.names3=g.names3, 
g.names4=g.names4, 
g.names5=g.names5, 
g.names6=g.names6, 
g.names7=g.names7, 
g.names8=g.names8,
g.names9=g.names9, 
g.names10=g.names10, 
g.names11=g.names11, 
g.names12=g.names12, 
g.names=g.names)

gt.names
```

Initially the problem seemed to be logically solved with the proposed solution below,

```
g.names <- list()
for (i in 1:13) {
   g.names[[i]] <- NULL
}
g.names
```

Interestingly, this did not work!  Assigning NULL to an object within a list is actually equivalent to delete. So, now the question still stands.

Comment: it's easy to do with the `*apply` family of functions and `assign`, but, more importantly, why do you want to do this? it's usually a bad idea to pollute your namespace with scalar objects. Perhaps you really just want to create a `list` named `g.names` in which you'll store all the `g.names*` objects?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, could you elaborate on namespace pollution and scalar objects?  

At the end of my function I simply do, gt.names<-list(g.names1=g.names1, etc...) followed by, return(gt.names).  So the only output is the gt.names list.  Is there a prettier way?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your function? Having a bunch of variables lying around with different integer suffixes isn't a good sign. Most likely the data could have been directly placed into a list with `lapply()` or `Map()`.

Comment: @MrFlick  What i am doing is populating these lists with cell names using keypresses as i sort through my data.    if(keyPressed=="1");
        {g.names1<-union(g.names1,cnames[cell.i]);print(g.names1)};
  if(keyPressed=="!");
        {g.names1<-setdiff(g.names1,cnames[cell.i]);print(g.names1)}

Answer (score 1):

The "polluted" way of doing this is through `assign` and `for` loop:

```
x <- c("", 1:12)
y <- paste("g.names", x, sep="")
for (v in y) {
  assign(v, NULL)
}
```

As commenter noted, the method above is very polluted... Here's an example of using list:

```
g.names <- list()
for (i in 1:13) {
  g.names[[i]] <- NULL
}
g.names
```

Here you would create a `list` object that hold the values of 13 variables, corresponding to `g.names`, `g.names1`, ... , `g.names12` in your original example. You can use `g.names[[6]]` to refer to your `g.names5`. It's less polluted and more "elegant" I guess.

And if the 13 `g.names` are going to be just series of characters or numbers, a vector will do:

```
g.names <- rep(NULL, 13)
g.names
```

and in this case `g.names[6]` will be equivalent to `g.names5` in your question.

Comment: Awesome.  Great idea, this will clean up the code quite a bit.  Will use the list method.

Comment: Sorry, but the list function does not work.  Assigning g.names[[i]]<-NULL is a way to erase a part of a list resulting in an empty list at the end of the function.  First part does work though

Comment: can try assigning 0 or NA instead of NULL... you'll eventually assigning an object onto each slot of the list anyway